# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I encounter this error when trying to insert the comments user edited under my UPDATE SQL statement. As my UserId is an uniqueIdentifier, I do not really know how to solve this error.

The error shows:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table
```

My .cs code is:

```
 int CommentID = int.Parse(ListView1.DataKeys[e.ItemIndex].Value.ToString());
    ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[e.ItemIndex];
    TextBox Title = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Title");
    TextBox commentContent = (TextBox)item.FindControl("commentContent");

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "Update Comments set Title = @Title, commentContent=@commentContent where CommentID = @CommentID";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentContent", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommentID", CommentID);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? It shows an Update statement and the message complains about an insert. Any triggers on the table?

Comment: I suspect you've got a trigger on the comments table which is causing this. I'm guessing you've got a UserID column on the comments table which allows NULLS (and has at least one NULL value in), whilst the table the trigger inserts into has a NOT NULL definition on it's UserID column.

Answer (score 1):

I think the UserID column in the table is having NOT NULL constraint.Check your table schema.

Comment: Yes, My UserId is not null. Beacuse it is the foreign key in my comments table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, the UserID has a not null constraint. Check in your database for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that UserId is your foreign key, you must define one foreign key

Comments contains UserId as Foreign Key, you must set UserId, because key can't be null